# Problem with connecting to Husky via USB port

Tags: roslaunch, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run Husky and using the instruction for husky in fuerte

However, when I use this command "roslaunch husky_bringup base.launch port:=/dev/ttyUSB0" it gives me the following error:
connecting error on /dev/ttyUSB0. Will retry every second

Does anyone have any idea what is the source of problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72838/problem-with-connecting-to-husky-via-usb-port/) by [z.bagheri63](https://answers.ros.org/users/5896/z.bagheri63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're working on this directly with @z.bagheri63 via our support line at the moment, but to make sure the answer is out here: We believe that the root cause is that there is more than one ROS instance trying to access the serial port.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0